# What is the recommended way to synchronize threads running on different services that share a database?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, multithreading, transactions, synchronization

I am working on an expensive data processing job that needs to run every 3 hours.  The job itself takes 1 hour to run.

The results of the job are stored in a Postgres database.  The job is part of a REST service that runs on multiple threads across multiple servers across multiples clusters.  In other words, a request, through load balancing can go to 1 of many threads that could be running on different servers in possibly different clusters.

The thread receiving the request is responsible for triggering the data processing job and I am using a Spring scheduling system for the follow up job.

The challenge is how to ensure that a thread doesn't call a job if it has already been triggered by another thread in the last 3 hours.  I need to account for the possibility of collisions as two threads might attempt to start a new instance of the expensive job at the same time.

Will it be sufficient to use @Transactional and two-phase commit to handle this?

I am thinking that I can synchronize using two-phase commit where a thread will register its ip address, thread id and then only run the job if their registration was successful.

```
@Transactional
public void saveJobInfo(JobInfo jobInfo) throws SQLException {
    repository.save(jobInfo);
}
```

Is there any problem with this approach?  Is @Transactional sufficient or do I need to specify a specific isolation level?